# ExpandableListView can't expand list with where condition

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Well i have a file .xaml with my listview. My list is binding with **Fournisseurs** in my MainViewModel. When i click on the button **MoreDetail** with the function **Button_Clicked** my list expand. But now, i added a checkbox if the checkbox is true, not problem my list is complete and when i click on the MoreDetail button i show all of the information.

But when the checkbox is false i have a list with only valids fournisseurs (where condition) but when i click on MoreDetail, my item doesn't expand. 
I think the problem come from the condition.

If you want I can share my code on GitHub.

.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
         <local:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView   
                  x:Name="FournisseursListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Fournisseurs}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  Margin="0,0,0,15"
                  ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped"
                  BackgroundColor="White"
                >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="1" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Button Image="{Binding .AfficheInfo}"
                                         Margin="4,1,0,0"
                                         BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                                         BorderColor="White"   
                                         BorderWidth="0"   
                                         BorderRadius="0"
                                         WidthRequest="40" 
                                         HeightRequest="40"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout WidthRequest="250"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Spacing="0" >
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .LibelleFournisseurFormated}"
                                       TextColor="Navy"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .CodeFournisseur}"
                                       TextColor="Navy"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout >
                                    <Button Image="{Binding .MoreDetail}"
                                         Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                                         Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                         BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                                         BorderColor="White"   
                                         BorderWidth="0"   
                                         BorderRadius="0"
                                         WidthRequest="31" 
                                         HeightRequest="31"/>
                                 </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                                         Orientation="Vertical"
                                         Margin="10,5,0,0">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .CodeEntiteFournisseurFormated}" 
                                       TextColor="Navy"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .ActifFournisseurFormated}" 
                                       TextColor="Navy"
                                       Margin="40,0,0,0"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .EssoFournisseurFormated}" 
                                       TextColor="Navy"
                                       Margin="40,0,0,0"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                             </StackLayout>
                         </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:CheckBox 
                DefaultText="Afficher les fournisseurs inactifs" 
                Margin="0,0,0,15"
                CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged      

            />

      </StackLayout>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public MainViewModel() 
    {



        Fournisseurs = new ObservableCollection<Fournisseur>

        {
            new Fournisseur
            {
                CodeFournisseur = "100001A",
                LibelleFournisseur = "L'AGENCE OUATE",
                CodeEntiteFournisseur = "GCT",
                Adresse1Fournisseur = "100 RUE DU COLONNEL MOLL",
                Adresse2Fournisseur = "",
                CPFournisseur = "75017",
                VilleFournisseur = "PARIS",
                PaysFournisseur = "France",
                TelephoneFournisseur = "02.28.09.03.00",
                FaxFournisseur = "02.28.09.03.09",
                EmailFournisseur = "",
                BoolActifFournisseur = true,
                BoolEssoFournisseur = true,
                IsVisible = false,
            },
            new Fournisseur
            {
                CodeFournisseur = "100001A",
                LibelleFournisseur = "L'AGENCE OUATE",
                CodeEntiteFournisseur = "GCT",
                Adresse1Fournisseur = "100 RUE DU COLONNEL MOLL",
                Adresse2Fournisseur = "",
                CPFournisseur = "75017",
                VilleFournisseur = "PARIS",
                PaysFournisseur = "France",
                TelephoneFournisseur = "02.28.09.03.00",
                FaxFournisseur = "02.28.09.03.09",
                EmailFournisseur = "",
                BoolActifFournisseur = false,
                BoolEssoFournisseur = true,
                IsVisible = false,
            }
      };

     public void ShowOrHideDetailFournisseur(Fournisseur Fournisseur)
        {
            if (_oldFournisseur == Fournisseur)
            {
                // click twice on the same item will hide it
                Fournisseur.IsVisible = !Fournisseur.IsVisible;
                UpdateFournisseurs(Fournisseur);

            }
            else
            {
                if (_oldFournisseur != null)
                {
                    // hide previous selected item
                    _oldFournisseur.IsVisible = false;
                    UpdateFournisseurs(_oldFournisseur);
                }
                // show selected item
                Fournisseur.IsVisible = true;
                UpdateFournisseurs(Fournisseur);
            }

            _oldFournisseur = Fournisseur;
        }



        private void UpdateFournisseurs(Fournisseur Fournisseur)
        {

            var index = Fournisseurs.IndexOf(Fournisseur);
            Fournisseurs.Remove(Fournisseur);
            Fournisseurs.Insert(index, Fournisseur);


        }
```

.xaml.cs

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            var fournisseur = button.BindingContext as Fournisseur;
            var vm = BindingContext as MainViewModel;
            vm?.ShowOrHideDetailFournisseur(fournisseur);
        }

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, XLabs.EventArgs<bool> e)
        {
            var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
            var vm = BindingContext as MainViewModel;


            if (checkbox.Checked == true) 
            {

                FournisseursListView.ItemsSource = vm.Fournisseurs;
             }
            else
            {                 
                FournisseursListView.ItemsSource = vm.Fournisseurs.Where(x=> x.BoolActifFournisseur == true);


            }
         }
```

When checked : can expand an item 
[List checked with an expand item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWUYR.jpg)
When unchecked : item doesn't expand on click 
[List unchecked, item doesn't expand on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPsBg.jpg)

The problem is : I can expand a list without condition but when i put a condition like (where), i think my list doen't refresh and she doesn't expand.

Comment: Anybody ? I think it's a refresh or a list problem but i can't solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
private bool? _IsVisible;
    public bool? IsVisible
    {
        get { return _IsVisible; }
        set {
            _IsVisible = value;
            if(_IsVisible !=null)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }

    }
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {

                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

    private void UpdateProducts(Product product)
            {

                if(searchProducts != null && searchProducts.Count > 0)
                {
                    var index = searchProducts.IndexOf(product);
                    searchProducts.Remove(product);
                    searchProducts.Insert(index, product);
                }
                else
                {
                    var index = Products.IndexOf(product);
                    Products.Remove(product);
                    Products.Insert(index, product);
                }

            }



    private void ListView_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                var product = e.Item as Product;
                var vm = BindingContext as MainViewModel;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchbar.Text))
                {
                    vm.searchProducts = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
                }

                vm?.ShowOrHidePoducts(product);
            }






    private void onsearchchanged(object sender ,TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var vm = BindingContext as MainViewModel;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
                    windowslistview.ItemsSource = vm?.Products;
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
                    {

                        var detailsdata = vm?.Products.Where(i =>
                   i.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower())).ToList();

                        if(detailsdata !=null && detailsdata.Count> 0)
                        {
                            ObservableCollection<Product> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Product>(detailsdata as List<Product>);
                            vm.searchProducts = myCollection;
                            windowslistview.ItemsSource = detailsdata;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            windowslistview.ItemsSource = vm?.Products;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

1. need to implement IsVisible of INotifyPropertyChanged event
2. In listview tapped method  get the search bar details if search bar having test or not
3. in showorhide method please provide the detailsof searche list data.
4. remove the xmal code line  `ItemsSource="{Binding Fournisseurs}"`